# Mathematical background of the rotation part of a camera transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

When calculating a camera transformation matrix for computer graphics it is generally calculated by the Gram-Schmidt process that creates three orthogonal vectors out of the vector the camera is facing: The eye, the up and the right vector, constructed from the camera position $\vec{p}$, the viewing target $\vec{t}$ and the vector $\vec{up} = (0,1,0)$:

$$\vec{e} = \frac{\vec{p} - \vec{t}}{\vec{p} - \vec{t}}$$

$$\vec{r} = \frac{\vec{up} \times \vec{e}}{||\vec{up} \times \vec{e}||}$$

$$\vec{u} = \vec{e} \times \vec{r}$$

What I understand is that these three vectors nor create an orthonormal-system of three orthogonal vectors that can be used as a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. What I do not understand is why multiplying with the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{r}_x & \vec{u}_x & \vec{e}_x & 0 \\
\vec{r}_y & \vec{u}_y & \vec{e}_y & 0 \\
\vec{r}_z & \vec{u}_z & \vec{e}_z & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

rotates everything in place so the camera is facing along the negative z-axis. It needs to be a transformation of the coordinate system to a new basis. Does this only work with the assumption that every other vertex is written in terms of the common ${e_1, e_2, e_3}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$? This would mean that multiplying any vector written in the common basis by any matrix with the unit vectors of any orthonormal-system of the same vector space in their columns would transform these vectors to the new coordinate system. $\vec{e}$ is the "new" z-axis "down the camera's view", $\vec{r}$ is the "new" x-axis "to the right" and $\vec{u}$ is the "new" y-axis "up the paper". I can't get my head around the "Why?", but I can see that it is the case. Being an orthonormal matrix makes also $M^T = M^{-1}$, so at least that is computationally very easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

The 'why' is essentially the core of what matrix transformation *does*: looking at just the rotation piece of things for simplicity (so in other words, all transformations are linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$), the matrix $M=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$ 'carries' (upon right multiplication) the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ — that is, the unit $x$ vector — to the vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\d\\g\end{bmatrix}$ (You can do the multiplication by hand to see this; the terms simplify quite a bit). Likewise, the unit $y$ vector is carried to $\begin{bmatrix}b\\e\\h\end{bmatrix}$, and the unit $z$ vector is carried to $\begin{bmatrix}c\\f\\i\end{bmatrix}$.

But if a matrix $M$ carries some vector $\vec{v}$ to another vector $\vec{w}$, then $M^{-1}$ carries $\vec{w}$ to $\vec{v}$; that's the definition of an inverse. So the matrix you've written out, by definition, carries $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{r}_x\\ \vec{r}_y\\ \vec{r}_z\end{bmatrix}$ to the unit $x$ vector, etc.

Comment: And the reason it keeps consistency with the real world is because the way the unit vectors are mapped are themselves orthogonal so it keeps up with what we'd consider a "realistic look"?